# Convert jquery function to javascript GSAP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing some experimentation with GSAP library and i found one pen by Jonathan

```
http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/qxsfc
```

which is pretty much i needed. i forked that pen and made my own and now i am trying to convert the same in vanilla js but the first step it self is not working. 
i have converted the anonymous function to a named one and called on window.onload and its working. but now i have to replace all the $ calls of jquery selector to native selectors and its not working
the moment i change

```
    var animContainer = $('.animContainer'),
to     var animContainer = document.querySelector('.animContainer'),
```

my pen is

```
`http://codepen.io/osricmacon/pen/HAnrt`
```

any more suggestion on how to go about converting jquery to vanilla js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelector` stops at the first element it finds, and returns a reference to that one element (or `null` if it doesn't find it). A closer analogue to jQuery's `$()` is `querySelectorAll`, which looks for *all* matching elements and returns a `NodeList` (which will be empty if none were found).

Separately from that, the key thing about jQuery is that it's *set-based*, whereas the DOM API is not. That's probably going to be the biggest thing for you to deal with when converting the one to the other.

For example, in jQuery, this sets the HTML of all `div` elements to "hey":

```
$("div").html("hey");
```

The equivalent using the DOM API might look like this:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("div"); // Or .getElementsByTagName
var i;
for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
     list[i].innerHTML = "hey";
}
```

A common approach to making that less verbose is to reuse `Array`'s `forEach` function (which is ES5, but can be shimmed for older browsers), like this:

```
// You'd probably do this once and reuse it
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

// Where you want to use it:
forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"), function(div) {
    div.innerHTML = "hey";
});
```

Or, of course, to have a toolbelt of utility functions that do that under the covers. Which is, of course, exactly what jQuery is.

Finally, in many cases jQuery reuses the same functions as both setters and getters. The `html` function, for instance, *sets* the HTML of the elements in the jQuery set when you give it an argument, but *gets* the HTML of the *first* element of the set if you don't:

```
$("div").html("hey");         // Sets the HTML of all divs
console.log($("div").html()); // Gets the HTML of the *first* div
```

Note the assymetry: Setting applies to all elements in the set, but getting applies only to the first element in the set (ignoring any others). This is true of all of the functions that do dual duty (`html`, `css`, `val`, `attr`, `prop`, ...).

Comment: Well somewhat i got what i was looking from your answer the key lies in learning javascript thoroughly so that its not at all dependent on jquery.. for each jquery function you have to write your own function